# Refactoring a Form into a separate component causes it to stop working correctly?

Tags: reactjs, forms, antd

Here is a codesandbox showing my issue
https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-voice-tt4my

This uses the Form, Input and Button component from Ant Design. The following render function does not work as expected. When I type in the form it loses focus on every key press...

```
render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;

    const SimpleFormItem = ({ name, label }) => {
      return (
        <Form.Item label={label}>
          {getFieldDecorator(name, {
            rules: [
              {
                required: true,
                message: `Please input ${label}!`
              }
            ]
          })(<Input />)}
        </Form.Item>
      );
    };

    return (
      <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <SimpleFormItem name="username" label="User Name" />

        <Form.Item>
          <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
            Create
          </Button>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    );
  }
```

However if I use the exact same JSX but pull it out of SimpleFormItem and use it directly, then it works fine...

```
render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;

    return (
      <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <Form.Item label="User Name">
          {getFieldDecorator("username", {
            rules: [
              {
                required: true,
                message: `Please input User Name!`
              }
            ]
          })(<Input />)}
        </Form.Item>

        <Form.Item>
          <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
            Create
          </Button>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    );
  }
```

I would expect these two examples to behave identically, what is the problem with the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function component must be created outside of the App class.
See: https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-sunset-ub0q0

<s>If `getFieldDecorator` is case sensitive, then `getFieldDecorator("Username" ...` is not the same as `getFieldDecorator("username" ...`. Might just be that you didn't copy the case of the "u" correctly.</s>

Comment: I corrected it so both examples have the same capitalization, but it's not the cause of the problem. Either upper or lowercase U works, it just changes how the field appears when submitted.

Comment: @Esostack I have updated my answer for why it is not working. I didn't realize you added a sandbox to test with.

Answer (score 0):

I think your form is re-rendering on every keystroke. I think this is a complication introduced by the ant Design library. They even have it as a FAQ in their documentation:

FAQ#
Why Input lose focus when change prefix/suffix#
When Input dynamic add or remove prefix/suffix will make React recreate the dom structure and new input will be not focused. You can set an empty  element to keep the dom structure:

```js
const suffix = condition ? <Icon type="smile" /> : <span />;

<Input suffix={suffix} />;
```